# What happens when a USA congress/senate candidate concedes while the vote count is still going? I mean can they still win?

Tags: united-states, election, congress

I just have general question about concedings:

Let's say in scenario a democratic congressman/senator concedes while a large percent of the votes are still being counted. The large batch of uncounted votes would turn the tide in his/her favor.

So my question is: Can he/she still claim victory afterwards?

Comment: So let me just get this straight: Conceding is just basically a public formality? A gesture of sorts? Is that Correct?

Comment: Actually, it is more a matter of public grace (accepting defeat with grace and dignity). Candidates can claim anything they want (and usually do), vote counting continues as required by law.

Answer (score 2):

The complete counting of votes in an election is a requirement of law. A concession speech does not stop the counting of ballots.

When the vote count is announced (by the legal authority) at the end of the counting process the announcement is the total votes for each candidate for each office rather than so-and-so won.